# Pay later for Membership - How does the membership get entered?

Tags: civimember

Civi v4.6.2 When entering a membership via the online contribution and using the Pay Later option I notice the membership does not get created.  Does an admin type person have to manually enter the membership?

Answer (score 2):

The membership is created when the payment is (manually) entered.

Comment: Jon - what do you think of my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

The Membership record is created at the outset along with the Contribution record, but is set to Pending/Inactive. You should be able to replicate this with the following steps on Demo.

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/amount?reset=1&action=update&id=2 and tick Pay Later (and add Pay Later instructions) so it is an option on the form.

Go to this contribution form logged out. http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2 and enter email and set to 'pay by cheque'. Complete process.
Logged in again find your contact that was just created (in my case http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=230)
Note that Membership tab says '0' and Contribution tab says '1' BUT click on Membership Tab and you will see the PENDING membership that is connected to the Contribution that is 'pending pay later'.

WHen money is received can then either complete the Contribution via the Contribution record, or via the Membership record (which opens up the Contribution record internally so to speak).

Once the Contribution is COMPLETED, the Pending Membership is then changed to Status = NEW, and Start/End date are created.

Hope that helps

NOTE: both Find Member and Member Dashboard do not show this pending membership at the top of the recent lists as they are sorted by date, and the pending membership has no date until payment is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Find the relevant contact record, edit the contribution that was created by the Pay Later option, and mark the Contribution status as Completed.  The membership will then be created.